# Odd behavior of PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, pdo

I have a PDO statement that for some reason refuses to execute properly. It returns false. However, when running the exact same statement using PDO's query(), it works like it should . . .

This is the relevant code:

```
// Prepare PDO statement
$getStatus = $dbHandle->prepare("SELECT `active` FROM `teachers`
                                 WHERE `id` = :teacher LIMIT 1;");
$getStatus->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$getStatus->bindParam(':teacher', $teacher_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// This statement retrieved the relevant teacher id;
// or false, if an invalid teacher was specified; in this
// case, we specify a valid teacher
$teacher_id = array_search($_POST['teacherName'], $acronyms);

// For debugging: show $teacher_id
echo("$teacher_id<br />");

// Execute query; should return an associative array
$newStatusArray = $getStatus->fetch();

// Nothing . . .
print_r($newStatusArray);

// returns "bool(false):
var_dump($newStatusArray);

// Trying with a query
foreach ($dbHandle->query("SELECT `active` FROM `teachers`
                           WHERE `id` = $teacher_id LIMIT 1;") as $row) {
  // This loop runs only once because of the LIMIT 1
  $newStatus = $row['active'];
}

// This prints the new status (was changed before, is always 0 or 1)
echo("$newStatus<br />");
```

The normal query, although it *should* do exactly what the prepared statement does, works; but the prepared statement returns nothing . . .

`$getStatus->errorCode()` is empty . . . So MySQL is happy. Also, `$getStatus->debugDumpParams()` shows what it's supposed to:

```
SQL: [62] SELECT `active` FROM `teachers` WHERE `id` = :teacher LIMIT 1;
Params: 1 Key: Name: [8] :teacher paramno=-1 name=[8] ":teacher"
is_param=1 param_type=1
```

I have been trying to get this to work for over an hour now, but I seriously don't get what's going wrong. Can anybody see what's the problem here?

I would greatly appreciate any pointers!

/////////////////////////////////////////////// EDIT: ///////////////////////////////////////////////

Thank you for your answers! So stupid - indeed, I had forgotten the execute statement. Duh . . . Very, very embarassed. Sorry for having taken up your time with this!!! Like this, it does work:

```
if (!$getStatus->execute()) {
  errorHandler("Errorcode: {$getStatus->errorCode()},
                errorinfo: {$getStatus->errorInfo ()}.");
}
$newStatusArray = $getStatus->fetch();
var_dump($newStatusArray);
```

The bindParam *can* stay at the top; which is in line with my understanding of the value of this method; you can just designate a variable to a slot in the PDO statement, and the whenever the query is executed, the value of the variable at that moment is passed along.

Comment: What is the `LIMIT 1` for? Do you have more than one teacher with the same id? If so, why didn't you make it a primary key? If not; there will never be more than one result :)

Comment: Actually, id _is_ a primary key :-) I hadn't realised that with primary keys, the LIMIT 1 is implicit. I tend to use it to speed up MySQL a bit (i.e. it immediately stops when it found a 'hit'), but you're right, in this case MySQL probably does that anyway because it knows this field is the primary key!

Comment: Don't believe everything you hear. MySQL will still have to search for that one row. If it's a primary key, MySQL is smart enough to realise that there will never be more than one row with that identifier. You can benchmark, but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know - thank you! Usually, when I use LIMIT 1, it's about primary keys anyway - I guess that kind of makes sense, because in that situation you're always sure there's only one :-) Good to know I can omit it from now on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to actually `->execute()` your statement.

```
$getStatus->execute(); // added
$newStatusArray = $getStatus->fetch();
```

Comment: That was it, thank you very much (see edited question). I'm sorry, but I can't vote you up (reputation too low) . . . But thank you very much!!!

Comment: @BerryLangerak Yes, but he will to wait some time before he can do that :)

Comment: @both - I did; and I did :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why your instruction:

```
$teacher_id = array_search($_POST['teacherName'], $acronyms);
```

goes after the bind instruction:

```
$getStatus->bindParam(':teacher', $teacher_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Maybe here is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm not sure however whether this is the solution; see my comment to Olaf's answer and the edited question . . .

Answer (score 0):

You bind `$teacher_id` before you retrieve the value from your `$_POST` parameters. If you move the `bindParam()` after that it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, if I understood correctly (and I may very well have understood incorrectly), this isn't necessary when binding variables; the values aren't read when binding, but when the query is executed. That's what I thought, at least? Otherwise, what's the value of bindParam over bindValue?